# OpenCV with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, aws-lambda

I wrote a Lambda function (Python 2.7) that uses OpenCV. I need to import CV2 and I'm having trouble providing the library in my .zip. Has anyone used OpenCV with Lambda? How can I provide the CV2 module.

Comment: I'n trying to do the same at the moment. I was going to try with a static version of openCV but looks like I still have some shared dependencies while trying to run it on lambda. Did you get any luck in that?

Comment: I haven't had time to go through and test this, and saw @RomanzoCriminale's similar query on another question. Have you tried anything like this with EC2? https://markn.ca/2015/10/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 4):

You must copy the **OpenCV** inside the zip that you send to AWS Lambda

This method helps to deploy with OpenCV https://github.com/aeddi/aws-lambda-python-opencv/blob/master/build.sh

Answer (score 1):

If you're only dealing with `cv2`, I would suggest adding it as a layer - That way you can have access to opencv throughout all your lambda functions which have the same runtime.

I had to package both `cv2` and `scipy`, where the package size was a huge problem, and I came to the following solutions in the end.

Using the `serverless-python-requirements` package on [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com) helped me streamline this whole process and reduce the package size as well. Would definitely recommend checking it out.

[This is the guide that I followed](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/)

[Serverless python-requirements plugin](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#option-not-to-strip-binaries)

Make sure to leave the `strip` flag to `false` to avoid stripping binaries which leads to the problem "ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned",

This is what my final `serverless.yml` came out to be which gave me the results I wanted to package sklearn + cv2 as a layer:

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    useDownloadCache: true
    useStaticCache: false
    slim: true
    strip: false
    layer:
      name: ${self:provider.stage}-cv2-sklearn
      description: Python requirements lambda layer
      compatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
      allowedAccounts:
        - '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build your code in Amazon Linux environment.

Please see my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649170/996926

Answer (score 0):

You must to add cv2 like a Lambda Layer. Check [this repo](https://github.com/076923/aws-lambda-python-opencv-layer.git) and do the following steps:

1. Clone the repo
2. Pick a version of opencv
3. Upload to a bucket
4. Create a Lambda Layer with the zip
5. Add the Layer to your Lambda.

it's all, enjoy it