# Opencv and AWS Lambda

Tags: opencv, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda function in Java ad want to use the opencv library. I am having a hard time understanding how to set it up. Please help. I can set it up just fine locally but I am really confused about the lambda part.

Edit: To be precise I am having trouble with System.LoadLibrary() function. The dll is in the project files but lambda cannot find it.

Comment: Please state exactly what it is you are trying to do with OpenCV and Lambda, so we can better help you. Lambda is essentially a remote code runner that will do whatever you want, when it is triggered. The applications are really endless, so you must be specific in your question.

Refer to this and try again http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What I don't get is how the lambda code will load the native library. I want to process images coming in from S3.

Comment: A dll is for a Windows environment, and Lambda runs in a Linux environment, so that's not going to work. Did you look at this article? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - we need to see what you've tried and what the specific problem is.

Comment: Actually I don't know how else to put it. I'm writing the Lambda function in java and want to use the opencv  functions with it. I've tried configuring the project by adding the jar and dll and .so files to the project structure but somehow the Unsatisfiedlink error always comes up.

Comment: Check this link out; hopefully you are using one of the require build tools http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I recommend using Node.js instead of Java because Lambdas work better with Node.js.

Your code will look like this:

```
cv = require('opencv');
//do something with cv...
```

But before being able to run the code you should install [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) and its [node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv):

```
npm install opencv
```

This will create a `node_modules` folder. Once ran your code locally, you need to do one extra step and then zip up everything (i.e. `your-code.js` and `node_modules` folder) into `lambda-package.zip` and upload it to an AWS Lambda.

**Extra step for Lambda:**

Lambda code runs in Amazon Linux environment (not your local environment). That means you should build the node packages in that environment. You may launch an EC2 instance and do the **npm install** part in that machine or you may use a docker image.

Here's a nice article about this:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it was about Java

Comment: @povman I had to go with python eventually. Nodejs and python are easier to deal with in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Opencv is dependent on underlying OS library files. For windows we need to have opencv_javaXXX.dll file and for windows we need libOpencv_javaXXX.so file (where XXX is the opencv version). In case if you don't have these files please generate using this link http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

AWS lambda basically uses an AMI name: amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.3.x86_64-gp2. This is a 64 bit linux machine. To get the libOpencv_javaXXX.so I spinned up an EC2 instance using AMI name: amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.3.x86_64-gp2 (This is a public AMI on amazon) and installed opencv for java on this machine.

Once you have libOpencv_javaXXX.so , add it to classpath (I added it to src/main/resources) and then  use following code to load it from JVM process.

```
System.load(new ClassPathResource("/libopencv_javaXXX.so").getFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

System.LoadLibrary() loads the library from java lib path and System.Load() will load the native library from the absolute path.